# Meaning of "sib of 20" in a by-patient case description table

Tags: terminology

A table from from *Cerebral folate deficiency: Analytical tests and differential diagnosis*:

> [image]

The first column contains patient numbers.
I thought that **sib of ..** meant "sibship of .." - that is, "in the patient's family, there is a total of NUMBER sisters and brothers". But when I came across "sib of 18" and "sib of 20" I started having second thoughts. Are there really families with such huge numbers of children?

What could be an alternative meaning for the abbreviation **sib** here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

21 (sib of 20) means that the person No 21 is a sibling of the person No 20 (a row before him).

You can check [this article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1744-313X.2006.00643.x):

> These patients were members of 28 unrelated kindreds with subjects **5
>   and 27,** 9 and 13, 10 and 12, 11 and 15 and 19 and 21, being full
>   siblings (Table 1).

In the table 1, you can see that the person No 5 is a sib of the person No 27, and the person No 27 is a sib of a person No 5.